Norm of $\zeta_n^k-1$ in $\Bbb Z[\zeta_n]$
Let $n\geq2$ be an integer, $\zeta_n=\exp(\tfrac{2\pi i}n)$ and $N(x)$ be the norm of $x\in\Bbb Z[\zeta_n]$.
Let $1\leq k\leq n-1$. Is it true that
$$N(\zeta_n^k-1)=\left(\Phi_{\tfrac n{\gcd(n,k)}}(1)\right)^{\frac{\phi(n)}{\phi(\gcd(n,k))}}$$
where $\Phi_m(x)$ is the cyclotomic polynomial of $\zeta_m$ and $\phi(m)$ is the Euler's totient function.
If not, what is the correct formula?
Thanks in advance.

I think the formula fails for $(n,k)=(16,4)$, and that you should replace $\phi(gcd(n,k))$ with $\phi(n)/\phi(n/gcd(n,k))$.

Thank you very much. I edited.  @Aphelli Can you write the proof? I am confused.

Step 1: show the number $z := \zeta_n^k$ is a root of unity with order $m := n/(k,n)$.
Step 2: use transitivity of the norm mapping on field extensions to show
$$
{\rm N}_{\mathbf Q(\zeta_n)/\mathbf Q}(z-1) = {\rm N}_{\mathbf Q(z)/\mathbf Q}(z-1)^{\varphi(n)/\varphi(m)}.
$$
You wrote ${\rm N}_{\mathbf Q(\zeta_n)/\mathbf Q}(x)$ as $N(x)$, but that leaves out the field extension, which makes it harder to express transitivity of the norm mapping.
Step 3: show the minimal polynomial of $z-1$ over $\mathbf Q$ is $\Phi_m(T+1)$, which has constant term $\Phi_m(1)$.
Step 4: Put everything together.

Steps are not good.

I outlined a way to solve the problem. If there is a step you can't work out, say what you tried and where you got stuck.

Thanks for your answer. I  wanted to have an elementary solution which uses only the definition of norm.

I suggest first getting some solution so you know what the answer is and only then worrying about getting a more elementary  solution. By the way, there are multiple ways to define the norm, so without saying how you define the norm it will be unclear what counts as a solution only using the definition.
